# Javascript: When using createElement function, how do you set a attribute to the created element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a game with a chatlog that displays damage done to you and the enemy. Instead of adding text nodes or paragrahs, I use a function that creates "DIV" elements per each time I log something. Realizing that DIV elements can be turned into buttons, I'm at a point where I want to make certain DIV's that get created in my chatlog clickable, and I thought I could do that by adding attributes / classes / ID's to the created DIV element. **How do I do that?** At the moment, I can created a infinite amount of DIV's, but i'm not quite sure how to assign specific ones attributes that will in turn, let me make them clickable buttons in the chatlog.

```
function logMessage(message) {
    var chatbox = dom.el("chatbox");
    chatbox.appendChild(document.createElement("div")).textContent = message;
    if (chatbox.children.length > 19) chatbox.removeChild(chatbox.children[0]);
    chatbox.scrollTop = chatbox.scrollHeight;
};


game = {
    start: function() {
        logMessage("Welcome to the Arena!");
        logMessage("Select your Fighter.");
        logMessage("DWARF"); // I want this to be clickable
        logMessage("2 Upgrade Points - 0 Skill Points.");
        logMessage("HUMAN"); // I want this to be clickable
        logMessage("1 Upgrade Point - 1 Skill Point.");
        logMessage("ELF"); // I want this to be clickable
        logMessage("0 Upgrade Points - 2 Skill Points.");
    },
```

Comment: Your code doesn't use jQuery, so why the tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can just store the new element as a variable, like anything else:

```
var myDiv = document.createElement('div');

chatbox.appendChild(myDiv);

myDiv.textContent = message;

myDiv.id = 'helloWorld';

myDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

^ Those are just some examples. I would take a look at [MDN Element docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) to see all the methods and attributes that you can mess around with.

Answer (score 0):

Elements have a `setAttribute` method, and there are named properties reflecting most attributes, too:

```
var messageElement = document.createElement('div');
messageElement.className = 'message';
//messageElement.setAttribute('class', 'message'); // equivalent
messageElement.textContent = message;
chatbox.appendChild(messageElement);
```